# Subscription to Windows Event Log?

Tags: c#, event-log, event-viewer

I'm working on a project that needs to check the Windows Event Log frequently for certain events. I'm wondering - is there a way to create a subscription to the Windows Event Log for certain events?

So, when the event happens (e.g. event id = 00001), I can get a notification in the code?

If this cannot be done, then I will have to keep searching the event log, which is not efficient.

Comment: to check the Event log there are several ways best way that I have found in the past was to use `WMI` worked wonders for me..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you're using C#, I think you should use Windows API to subscribe to certain Windows events. You can do it by using either `EventLogWatcher` or `EventLog` class. You can find an example of creating a Windows Event Log subscription using `EventLog` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

If you prefer `EventLogWatcher`, refer to its limited [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

And here is my example:

```
public static void subscribe()
{
    EventLogWatcher watcher = null;
    try
    {
        EventLogQuery subscriptionQuery = new EventLogQuery(
            "Security", PathType.LogName, "*[System/EventID=4624]");

        watcher = new EventLogWatcher(subscriptionQuery);

        // Make the watcher listen to the EventRecordWritten
        // events.  When this event happens, the callback method
        // (EventLogEventRead) is called.
        watcher.EventRecordWritten +=
            new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(
                EventLogEventRead);

        // Activate the subscription
        watcher.Enabled = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // Wait for events to occur. 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
    catch (EventLogReadingException e)
    {
        Log("Error reading the log: {0}", e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Stop listening to events
        watcher.Enabled = false;

        if (watcher != null)
        {
            watcher.Dispose();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

// Callback method that gets executed when an event is
// reported to the subscription.
public static void EventLogEventRead(object obj,
    EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
{
    // Make sure there was no error reading the event.
    if (arg.EventRecord != null)
    {
        //////
        // This section creates a list of XPath reference strings to select
        // the properties that we want to display
        // In this example, we will extract the User, TimeCreated, EventID and EventRecordID
        //////
        // Array of strings containing XPath references
        String[] xPathRefs = new String[9];
        xPathRefs[0] = "Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime";
        xPathRefs[1] = "Event/System/Computer";
        xPathRefs[2] = "Event/EventData/Data[@Name=\"TargetUserName\"]";
        xPathRefs[3] = "Event/EventData/Data[@Name=\"TargetDomainName\"]";

        // Place those strings in an IEnumerable object
        IEnumerable<String> xPathEnum = xPathRefs;

        // Create the property selection context using the XPath reference
        EventLogPropertySelector logPropertyContext = new EventLogPropertySelector(xPathEnum);

        IList<object> logEventProps = ((EventLogRecord)arg.EventRecord).GetPropertyValues(logPropertyContext);
        Log("Time: ", logEventProps[0]);
        Log("Computer: ", logEventProps[1]);
        Log("TargetUserName: ", logEventProps[2]);
        Log("TargetDomainName: ", logEventProps[3]);
        Log("---------------------------------------");

        Log("Description: ", arg.EventRecord.FormatDescription());
    }
    else
    {
        Log("The event instance was null.");
    }
}
```

Comment: i'll second that their documentation is terrible

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified example, which uses the query generated in the *XML* tab on the filter view of the Windows Event Viewer. It loads the initial records returned by the query, then keeps watch for any future items.

```
var query = $"*[System[(EventID=1942) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 604800000]]]";
var decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(query);
var eventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, decoded);
var watcher = new EventLogWatcher(eventLogQuery, null, true);
var count = 0;

watcher.EventRecordWritten += (object sender, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs e) =>
{
    count += 1;

    Console.WriteLine($"Found {count} items for query");
};

watcher.Enabled = true;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```